# U&L favicon on dark background is barely readable

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

On Firefox with Dark theme enabled (it is available in the browser out of the box), this site's favicon is mostly unreadable:

[image]

The letters could have less transparency and more white in them so that it would fix the look on dark backgrounds while leaving the appearance on white unchanged.