# AWS will soon be sponsoring Unix & Linux

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) will be sponsoring Unix & Linux beginning September 27, 2021 through December 31, 2022. We wanted to give you a heads up and walk you through what it will look like.

## How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown in the top right header of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: unixlinushomepage]

## What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside
> our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the
> questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections
> as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a
> garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits
> still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has
> always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all
> Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for
> sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

## What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off please report it as a [bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug). so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns please leave them as answers below.

Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Unix & Linux successful.

Comment: We had the [IBM sponsorship announcement](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/ibm-will-soon-be-sponsoring-unix-linux) in the past but the staff conveniently ignored some of the answers. The concerns raised there also apply to this.

Comment: Btw, for how much time they're sponsoring?

Comment: @Pandya it says "beginning September 27 through December 31"

Comment: @maulinglawns I fail to understand the remark. Could you help me scross the street?

Comment: https://v.gd/1hVnqp

Comment: Nice but I still wonder why going through Doubleclick is needed. It also seems likely to severely underperform and/or undercount clicks and interest from this site's audience, cf. https://plausible.io/blog/google-analytics-adblockers-missing-data

Comment: AWS extended its sponsorship to March 31. I've updated the post to reflect the new dates.

Comment: AWS extended its sponsorship to April 30. I've updated the post to reflect the new dates.

Comment: AWS extended its sponsorship to June 30. I've updated the post to reflect the new dates.

Comment: AWS extended its sponsorship to the end of the year. I've updated the post to reflect the new dates.